# IntelliJ IDEA: how to find all instance creation of a class?

Tags: intellij-idea, structural-search

```
abstract class Base {}

class A extends Base
class B extends Base
```

How do I find all places in the code that create *Base*? (that is, have either new `A()` or new `B()`)

**UPDATE**
To make it clear, the above is just and example. I'm interested in a way of searching for object creation of any class, including 3rd party classes that I don't control.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Using Structural Search (Edit -> Find -> Search Structurally):

- Create a template: `new $Type$($P$)`
- Edit Type variable: type Base in the text field, check 'Apply constraint within type hierarchy', check 'This variable is target of the search'
- Edit P variable: type .* in the text field, set Minimum count to 0, check Unlimited under Maximum count.

Voila!

Comment: For people of the future - Structural Search only works in Ultimate edition of IntelliJ.

Comment: This also works in Community Edition as of the 14 EAP (build IC-138.2210.3. I don't know if it'll be taken out in the Ultimate edition for 14.

Answer (score 8):

IttayD if I have understood correctly your latest update, what I normally do (IntelliJ 9.0.4) if I have a similar need to yours is Right click on class name and do *"Find Usages"* and this will list results in the form of usage categories,

- Variable declaration
- New Instance creation, to name a few.

As far as I'm aware I do not think there is a specific option/selection choice to fulfill such a usage search check. Thanks

[image]

Comment: Find Usages returns only creation of instances of that class, not of subclasses of this class (or trait)

Comment: @IttayD under find usages instantiated subclasses of the 'abstract' class should be listed under 'local variable declaration' for e.g. I did give this a try and it listed all initialised instaces of subclasses. Maybe you can paste some e.g. code you have which does not lists under find usages. thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can create empty default constructor of Base and press  <kbd>Ctrl+Alt+H</kbd>  (Hierarchy Callers). Then you'll see all creations of A and B in as a tree.